# condition waiting thread consuming too many cpu cycles

Tags: java, multithreading

Sorry for the possibly naive question, but s it normal for a thread in condition wait state (CW) to consume too many CPU cycles? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

No.  If it *is* in a wait state permanently, it should not be consuming cycles.    However, it can be spinning and then waiting and you have only been able to catch it when it is in its wait state.  For example, it could be waiting on an object for a couple of milliseconds in some sort of loop and then consuming CPU cycles the rest of the time.  If you check the thread status at a higher frequency, you should be able to see this.

If you provide more information about how you know it is in a wait state I'll edit my answer to provide more information.